# Django urls. Click on the button and redirect to the same page

Tags: django, date, url, redirect, controller

Hej, 
I have a problem with urls. Through the button I'm passing to the url appropriate id, in controller I'm taking this id and assign it to the current date to save it in database (table with users then admin clicks on "attend" and save lastAttendance in database). I'm stacked with urls cause after clicking it doesn't redirect me to the same page. Any advices appreciated!

MODEL:

```
class Donor(models.Model):
firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
bloodType = models.CharField(max_length=10)
createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
lastAttendance = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^donors/get?attend=(\d+)/$', views.donors,  name='donors'),
```

VIEW:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def donors(request):
    global message
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 

# context = RequestContext(request)
donor_id = None
if request.method == "GET":
    donor_id = request.GET.get('id')

if donor_id:
    donor = Donor.objects.get(id=int(donor_id))
    if donor:
        donor.lastAttendance = datetime.datetime.now()
        donor.save()

#display all the lates added donors
query_results = Donor.objects.order_by('-createdDate')
#dislay total ammount of rows
donors_count = Donor.objects.count()

return render(request, 'donors.html', {
    'form': PostForm(), 
    'donors_count': donors_count,
    'query_results': query_results,       
    })
```

HTML:

```
  <button 
type="submit" 
class="btn attendBtn" 
value="{{ item.id }}" 
name="attend">attend
```

OUTPUT
[output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0TBi.png)

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: please show the template

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a question mark in your URL as it is seen as a parameter for the URL. Try this instead:

```
url(r'^donors/get/attend/(\d+)/$', views.donors,  name='donors'),
```

Which would result in an URL such as

```
https://example.com/donors/get/attend/12456
```

Comment: it is still the same output, but even if i remove  this line from url when i click on the button it still redirects me to :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/donors/get?attend=3

is there a trick with name and value in the button?